Teacher needing helping with student's voice
So I am a private teacher and have a fourteen year old student that has a very hard time singing above an A5. Her voice either cuts out or is very unsupported and airy. It is also very shaky. There is no pain when she sings and her low voice is very nice. I've tried her opening her mouth more, more support, different vowel chats and different warm ups to help her access her head voice. Is there any warmups to assist with her voice?

This needs some explanation of why it's important that she move beyond A4, or why that isn't just the limit of her range.

@Aaron Your comment is spot on, although traditionally a singer who identifies as female would be quite unusual to not be able to go above A4. Nowadays there’s much less correlation between gender and range.

@ToddWilcox I took the question to mean below A4.

@Aaron I feel like that would be equally surprising. Although... if the asker is using the Yamaha MIDI standard of calling middle C "C3", then "A4" would mean A5 in SPN, and that might be too high for a trained contralto and a challenge for a less-trained soprano.

@ToddWilcox Ah, you're right. I was thinking A3.

@Aaron - isn't head voice (mentioned in post) higher than chest voice?

@Tim good point. Missed that. It begs the question of why the student would need head voice at such a low pitch.

@Aaron - Weird, I've read that the female head voice transition is at around the E to F above Middle C, definitely off from A4. This seems like an unusual case...

My apologies, I was at my other teaching job and didn’t proof read as much as I should. She cannot sing above an A5 or A above middle C

@user98378 - Wait, you really do mean the A above Middle C, not the A above the C above Middle C?

Because when we warm up with lip buzzes, she can reach a E5-F5

Training the high register takes time, care and control. Why is it important that a 14 year old girl can sing above A5? Try to train her technique in the range that works, and make sure she has fun doing so, so that she stays motivated. If you focus too much on things she can not do yet you’ll frustrate her. Start with warm up exercises that work well in the range that works, and then try to only gradually go higher in pitch, and try do understand what she is doing differently. But do not try to force it!
